# How to replace leading 0 with 91 using regex in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

In python I am doing this to replace leading 0 in column phone with 91. 
But how to do it in pyspark.

con  dataframe is :

```
id phone1
1   088976854667
2   089706790002
```

Outptut i want is

```
1   9188976854667
2   9189706790002
```

```
# Replace leading Zeros in a phone number with 91

con.filter(regex='[_]').replace('^0','385',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [regexp_replace](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) function. This function takes 3 parameter:

1. column name
2. pattern
3. repleacement

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
columns = ['id', 'phone1']
vals = [(1, '088976854667'),(2, '089706790002' )]


df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df = df.withColumn('phone1', F.regexp_replace('phone1',"^0", "91"))
df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+---+-------------+ 
| id|       phone1| 
+---+-------------+ 
|  1|9188976854667| 
|  2|9189706790002| 
+---+-------------+
```